# Account Login giving HTTP ERROR 400: This page isn’t working in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

The account login used to work fine, but now it gives error :

> **This page isn’t working**
>
> If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
>
> <sub>HTTP ERROR 400</sub>

The browser url is `https://localhost:7185/Account/Login?returnurl=%2F`

The only change from before is I have created a custom `_PartialView` for my Identity.

---

Here is my code-

AccountController.cs:

```cs
// Login
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string? returnUrl = null)
{
    LoginAccountViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginAccountViewModel();
    loginViewModel.ReturnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    return View(loginViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginAccountViewModel loginViewModel, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.UserName, loginViewModel.Password, loginViewModel.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }
    }
    return View(loginViewModel);
}
```

Edit:

After debugging, I found that the my code could not find the `[HttpPost]` in my controller hence giving error `No resource found`. I do not know why this is caused.

---

Update:

Login.cshtml:

```html
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-body-tertiary">

        <!-- Right Side -->
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
            <!-- OAuth -->
        </div>

        <!-- Left Side -->
        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
            <h4 class="mb-3">Account Login Details</h4>
            <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
                <div class="row g-3">                    

                    <!-- UserName -->
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label asp-for="UserName" class="form-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="input-group has-validation">
                            <span class="input-group-text">@@</span>
                            <input asp-for="UserName" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Your username is required.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label asp-for="Password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please enter atleast 6 characters.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr class="my-4">

                <!-- Remember Me -->
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                        <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </label>
                </div>

                <hr class="my-4">

                <!-- Login -->
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>

                <hr class="my-4">

                <!-- Register -->
                <p>
                    <a class="mb-5" asp-action="Register">Havent Registered yet?</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Page Console:
[image]

Page Source:
[image]

No other errors found.

---

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You mean you create a custom identity view and use it facing the issue? If you are using the asp.net core default identity login page the url is `asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login`. So you want to build you own identity login page? How you face this issue? During the post method or the get method?  Have you chcked the browser's F12 network trace to see the why it return the 400 error?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have created my custom Identity, yes. The issue I face is during `[HttpPost]`. The page source says `No resource with given URL found`. I have updated the F12 images.

Comment: Please add your login View, I guess the form post codes contains the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I did not debug my code before. After debugging, I found that the my code could not find the `[HttpPost]` in my controller hence giving error `No resource found`. I do not know why this is caused.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have updated my Login View

Comment: It may not be anything to do with your problem, but why are you using a ReturnURL parameter, if on success you always redirect to Home/Index?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I started ASP.NET little over 5 months ago. The code is what I learnt from YouTube video and I am using it to create my website. I still do not have full grasp of my own code and just starting to understand what everything does. In future I will rewrite the code properly. I am thankful to you for showing errors in the code. I would be grateful if you could show some pointers, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you face the 400 error is you don't set the validation token.

You should set the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside the form tag.

More details, you could refer to below login view codes:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="p-4 p-md-5 border rounded-3 bg-body-tertiary">

        <!-- Right Side -->
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
            <!-- OAuth -->
        </div>

        <!-- Left Side -->
        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
            <h4 class="mb-3">Account Login Details</h4>
            <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="row g-3">

                    <!-- UserName -->
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label asp-for="UserName" class="form-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="input-group has-validation">
                            <span class="input-group-text">@@</span>
                            <input asp-for="UserName" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Your username is required.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label asp-for="Password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please enter atleast 6 characters.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr class="my-4">

                <!-- Remember Me -->
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                        <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </label>
                </div>

                <hr class="my-4">

                <!-- Login -->
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>

                <hr class="my-4">

                <!-- Register -->
                <p>
                    <a class="mb-5" asp-action="Register">Havent Registered yet?</a>
                </p>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

Result:

[image]